# How do I know which Chrome binary to install on my VPS?

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I am attempting to do some web scraping from my VPS and I have already installed selenium and the chromedriver, however, now it looks like I need the Chrome binary in order to make everything work as expected.

I am on a Linux private server, how do I which binary to install to make my scraping work?

Comment: You probably need this https://geekflare.com/install-chromium-ubuntu-centos/

Answer (score 0):

Install any Chrome version with automatic update enabled or not.

Download it here:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Install (Debian):

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Install (Ubuntu):

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Then use this package [Webdriver Manager for Python](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

**How to install it**

```
pip3 install webdriver-manager
```

**How to use it**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()) as driver:
   ...
```

The package will identify the Chrome version installed and will fetch on github the proper driver binary. (If needed)